# Problem request timeout for looping with CURL

Tags: php, loops, web-scraping, http-headers, request-timed-out

I have script like this :

```
function getNewProductToEcommerce($merk, $shopID){
    // assuming I have called a database connection
    -----------------------------------------------
    $conn = intialitationDB();
    -----------------------------------------------
    $sql = "select * from tablebarang where merk = '".$merk."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $addNewProducts = array();
    foreach($result as $products){
        $tempSKU = searchEcommerceProducts($products['sku'], $shopID);

        if($tempSKU === false){
            $newProducts['sku'] = $products['sku'];
            $newProducts['catID'] = getCatIdEcommerece($merk, $products['sku']);
            $images = getPhotosSomeWebsite($merk, $products['sku']);
            for($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++){
                if(isset($images[$i-1])) $img = 'https://somewebsite.com/file/'.$images[$i-1];
                else $img = '';

                $newProducts['images_'.$i] = $img;
            }
            $addNewProducts['sku'][] = $products['sku'];
            $addNewProducts['item'][] = $newProducts;
        }
        // Markup
        // In here i should respone to user one by one, but i cannot because 
        i just need respone just some variable
    }
    return $addNewProducts;
    mysqli_close($conn);
}

function searchEcommerceProducts($sku, $shopID){
    $q = str_replace(" ","%2B", $sku);
    $url = "https://somewebsite.com/search/product?shop_id=$shopID&ob=11&rows=80&start=0&device=desktop&source=shop_product&q=$q";
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $html = json_decode($html, true);
    if($html["header"]["total_data"] >= 1) return true;
    else return false;
}

function getCatIdEcommerece($merk, $sku){
    $merk = str_replace(" ","%2B",$merk);
    $sku = str_replace(" ","%2B",$sku);
    $search = $merk . "%2B" . $sku;
    $url = "https://somesite.com/search/product/v3?scheme=https&device=desktop&catalog_rows=0&rows=1&source=search&ob=23&st=product&q=".$search."&sc=0&user_id=470833&rows=60&unique_id=35e66d287a5d4cefb1a674678be311f4";
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $html = json_decode($html, true);

    if (isset($html['data']['products'][0]['url'])){
        $url = $html['data']['products'][0]['url'];
        $cat_id = after_last ("catid%3D", $url);
    }else $cat_id = '';

    return $cat_id;
}

function getPhotosSomeWebsite($merk, $sku){
    $search = str_replace(' ','%20',$merk.' '.$sku);
    // assuming I have called a function name theCURL
    -----------------------------------------------
    $getFoto = theCURL("https://somesite.com/search_items/?by=relevancy&keyword=$search&limit=1&match_id=16775174&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=shop&__classic__=1",'GET','');
    -----------------------------------------------

    $getFoto = json_decode($getFoto, true);
    $items = $getFoto['items'];
    if(!empty($items)){
        $idProduct = $items[0]["itemid"];
        $getFoto = theCURL("https://somesite.com/item/get?itemid=$idProduct&shopid=16775174&__classic__=1",'GET','');
        $getFoto = json_decode($getFoto, true);
        return $getFoto['item']['images'];
    } else return null;
}
```

**Explanation :**

First :
I Need get variable of SKU, CategoryID, ImagesURL from my scraping website where I have not input the item in my shop, so i dont need check double product item / duplicate product.

Second :
I Call function `getNewProductToEcommerce()` from other class and just return variable SKU, CategoryID, ImagesURL in array. I need to save the product item to xlsx.

**The Problem :**

In looping i just want get some product where *I have not input the item in my shop*, but looping for 1000 sku product it taking too long time and return Request Timeout (just working for 100 sku product checking).

I have been duping the script using echo in looping foreach it's working fine for this 1000 sku product, but when i passing function it can't be and return error 'headers already sent by header'.

**My Question**

How i can get return function for many product without getting error 'headers already sent by header' or request time out in my problem ?

I am very grateful if someone can help me on this issue, thank you.

Comment: Anybody can help ?

Answer (score 0):

'**Headers already sent**' error occurs because PHP is printing some errors or warnings before you send the headers. Find what kind of error occurs. Most probably it is a php execution timeout issue in your case so try to increase the execution time limit in your php configuration file according to your needs:

In php.ini file:

```
max_execution_time=500
```

Also for memory limit:

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

If you don't have sufficient privileges to do that you may try to do your operations batch wise as a cron job.

Comment: I have been check but nothing error or warning, please check my script in question.

Comment: I also have been set max_execution_time=600
memory_limit = 512M
before execute, this is not solution.

Comment: Then what you mean by 'Request Timeout ' ? Do you see an empty page ? May be your error reporting is turn off by default.

Comment: request timeout because i using looping to much and just put in variable and not print out to webpage, so in user the webpage looks like as not responding, please see again my script problem.

Comment: See in my comment line // Markup